# Excel - "send to Mail recipient" creates 2nd copy of EMail in Inbox

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, send-to

When sending Excel sheets using the menu item "File" -> "Sent To" -> "Mail recipient (as attachment)" I get additional copies of the email in the Inbox.

When I press "send" then I get 2 copies of the email in Outlook - as expected one in the Outbox (which moves into the Sent folder as soon it is sent off) and an additional one in the Inbox.

How do I stop the copy message appearing in the Inbox?

System:
Excel 2000, Outlook 2000, Windows XP. Antivirus is AVG Free 2011.

I know this is a very old system, but it is not my PC and there isn't any chance to get it replaced in the near future yet.

SOme further details:
The copy in the inbox appears at the same time as the normal copy goes into the Outbox (i.e. as soon I press send). It doesn't contain anything in the From field (i.e. there is no sender, just the recipient of the mail). It has a different icon in Outlook to the other emails - the icon is the one for "saved or unsent message".

I tried it with a few different spreadsheets and it happens with all of them. It happens with every recipient, and it only happens if sending from within Excel (i.e. using the Send to menu item). I can delete the attachment before sending and it will still create a copy. If I create a new message in Outlook and then add the Excel document as attachment then I don't get the copy of the message in the inbox, it only happens when using the send to item in Excel.

It only started doing this recently. Around that time the Antivirus (AVG Free) was upgraded to the latest version (from the previous version - 2010? - to version 2011), but this might not be related.

I thought I know Excel really well but have never seen this happening before, and I can't find any setting in Excel or Outlook that is causing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: check the rules in outlook, maybe there is one that creates a cc to self on certain conditions.

Comment: No there are no rules or other settings in Outlook to copy self. It doesn't send the mail to self as cc would do, it creates an unsent copy with original to address and no from address in the inbox. It only does it when using send to in Excel, when creating emails in Outlook I don't get the copy. It must either be something in Excel or an interaction between Excel and AVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common in 2004 copies are saved to inbox not drafts when 'send as attachment' option is used-this would leave you with copy in sent and inbox. Save and send had same effect when 'send as' option was used.  There has probably been a patch/ upgrade to make it save a draft to drafts since this 2004 post. Perhaps this patch/upgrade has been removed in Excel by new avg? It should do this with all 'send to' file options - Word, Access, etc. I have not found any current question problems on this subject or info on patch or how to get it.

[A 2004 question/answer - info source.](http://www.mofeel.net/873-microsoft-public-outlook/45257.aspx)

Is there any other software installed or are you running iTunes? Have you tried 'hit and miss' to find the problem area? I do not have 2000 in XP.

- Turn off save copies, generic option in Outlook, then send Excel email.
- Turn off save copies, generic option in Excel - then send Excel email.
- Turn them both off and then turn all back on.

Check the group policy or try setting up a different user in Outlook and see if the problem persists (this would be a profile problem). Something that can get changed by a new anti-virus program.